# Symlink dll files from one folder to another using mklink

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, mklink

How can i symlink all the dll-s from another application to my bin folder if i don't have the option to copy local those dll's?

Something like:

```
mklink /h "C:\myApplication\bin\*.dll" "C:\directoryWithTheDlls\bin\*.dll"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to copy everything with this command:

```
 "/c mklink "C:\myApplication\bin\CopiedAssemblies" "C:\directoryWithTheAssemblies\bin" /j"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `loadlibrary` search order from Help.

> The directory from which the application loaded.
>
> The current directory. 
>   Windows XP: If HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\SafeDllSearchMode is 1, the current directory is the last directory searched. The default value is 0.
>
> The Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory. 
>   Windows NT/2000/XP: The name of this directory is System32.
>
> Windows NT/2000/XP: The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
>
> The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>
> The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

So add that directory to the path.